# RubyMine -e:1:in `sleep': Interrupt Debug zeus server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rubymine, zeus

I am trying to debug my custom rake file in a rails project. I followed the instructions of the official help page, and setup zeus server correctly. Every time I debug the zeus server, I get the message below:

Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.1.beta2, debase 0.2.2.beta8, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:49605
-e:1:in `sleep': Interrupt
    from -e:1:in`block in '
/Users/Mazz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:80:in `wait': Interrupt
    from /Users/Mazz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:80:in`block in prepare_debugger'
    from /Users/Mazz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/Mazz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:79:in`prepare_debugger'
    from /Users/Mazz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:85:in `debug_program'
    from /Users/Mazz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/bin/rdebug-ide:130:in`'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in`'

I don't know what it mean that "sleep : Interrupt", and how to fix it. Can anyone give me some ideas?

Thanks a million!